# The difference between IModelBinder and IModelBinderProvider asp.net mvc 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, modelbinders

The question is simple: when should I implement `IModelBinder` and when `IModelBinderProvider`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

`IModelBinderProvider` is a factory that supplies `IModelBinder` implementations. For simple cases where a type always uses the same model binder you just need to use IModelBinder. You would implement IModelBinderProvider for more complex cases where you need to dynamically determine which model binder to use.

[Jimmy Bogard](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2011/07/07/intelligent-model-binding-with-model-binder-providers/) and [Brad Wilson](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/service-location-pt9-model-binders.html) explain it better than I can.

Comment: And where would the `IModelBinderFactory` interface fit into this?  I'm using `IModelBinderProvider` now but I am wondering if I should implement the 'factory' method instead...

Comment: @ChristopherKing `IModelBinderFactory` is new in ASP.NET Core (whereas this entire QA is from 2012 and is about the old ASP.NET MVC). Anyway, you don't need to implement `IModelBinderFactory` yourself: ASP.NET Core has its own `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelBinderFactory` which is really just a class that caches `IModelBinderProvider` instances.

Answer (score 0):

When you use IModelBinderProvider you still need use IModelBinder for binder class

```
  We use IModelBinderProvider to help us don't need to register manual like
    ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(HomePageModels1), new HomeCustomBinder1());
    ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(HomePageModels2), new HomeCustomBinder2());

...
```

We just need add 1 line

```
ModelBinderProviders.BinderProviders.Add(new YourModelBinderProvider());
```

An when controller has parameter. it will auto call method

```
public IModelBinder GetBinder(Type modelType)
```

For you customize your model